# GitLab CI: Unable to test socketIO endpoints when FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD is 1

Tags: express, socket.io, gitlab

I use GitLab CI to perform the E2E tests on socket IO endpoints and it used to be working correctly until I set `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` to `1` in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

No specific error is thrown, what is the problem?

This is how I connect to socket server in Jest test:

```js
const address = app.listen().address(); // returns { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 42073 }
const baseAddress = `http://${address.host}:${address.port}`;
socket = io(baseAddress, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  auth: { token: response.body.token },
  forceNew: true,
});
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
image: node:16

stages:
    - dependencies
    - e2e
    - build

cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules

dependency_job:
    stage: dependencies
    script:
        - npm ci

test_e2e:
    stage: test
    variables:
        NODE_ENV: test
        PORT: 3000
        THROTTLE_TTL: 60000
        THROTTLE_LIMIT: 1
        SESSION_SECRET: somesecret
        DOMAIN: console.okhtapos.com
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/postgres?schema=public"
        REDIS_HOST: redis
        REDIS_PORT: 6379
        REDIS_VOLATILE_HOST: redis
        REDIS_VOLATILE_PORT: 6379
        SESSIONS_REDIS_PREFIX: "sess:"
        SESSIONS_SECRET: somesecret
        SESSIONS_NAME: omni-session
        GRPC_URL: localhost:5004
        OCTO_CENTRAL_GRPC_URL: localhost:5005
        CUSTOMERS_ATTRIBUTES_DATABASE_NAME: omnichannel-customer-attributes
        CUSTOMERS_ATTRIBUTES_MAX: 100
        CUSTOMERS_ATTRIBUTES_MAX_TOTAL_SIZE_IN_BYTES: 5000
        MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017
        CUSTOMERS_ATTRIBUTES_MAX_QUARANTINE_DAYS: 7
        KAFKA_BROKERS: kafka:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,INTERNAL://localhost:9093"
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "1"
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093"
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        LABELS_MAX_QUARANTINE_DAYS: 7
        LABELS_MAX: 100
        DEPARTMENTS_MAX: 100
        AUTHENTICATION_GATEWAY_SECRET: someGatewaySecret
        CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS: cassandra:9042
        CASSANDRA_LOCAL_DATA_CENTER: datacenter1
        CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE: omnichannel
        FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
        ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        BROKER_ID: 1

    services:
        - redis:latest
        - postgres:15beta3
        - mongo:latest
        - cassandra:latest
        - name: debezium/zookeeper:2.0.0.Beta1
          alias: zookeeper
        - name: debezium/kafka:2.0.0.Beta1
          alias: kafka

    script:
        - npx prisma generate
        - npx prisma migrate deploy
        - npm run test:e2e

build_job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm run build
```

Comment: Can you share you `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

Comment: One thing I suspect is the environment variables. If you set `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` environment variables are not passed on to the service containers. Use `services:-:variables` instead.